# jQuery deferred on potential asynch functions?

Tags: jquery, deferred

I'm wondering if JQuery deferreds are the best mechanism for my scenario

my main code depends on a function that calls an asynchronous service.
I don't want to continue until the function that calls the service completes.
The service has callbacks for success and failure.
My code doesn't know which will happen (I'm hoping success!).

Is jQuery deferreds meant for this, or is there a better mechanism?

so:
main code

```
step 1
step 2 call function X with asynch service
step 3 wait for function X results are in
step 4 do for success - go to done (bring back BASIC...not)
step 5 do for failure
step 6 done
```

function X

```
call asych service with callbacks for
    success (function S)
    failure (function F)
```

function S

```
yay, I have data - work in main code can continue
```

function F

```
icky, no data - can't continue work in main code
```

Comment: Can you paste your async function code ?

Comment: The “best” solution would probably be to use native promises or even `async/await`, but jQuery deferreds work too.

Comment: @FelixKling Could you show some examples?

Comment: @shanechiu: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: @FelixKling much appreciated.